# Mysql select ignores null values on return results

Tags: mysql

I have a table where a column is mostly NULL except for one row.

```
ID STATUS VALUE POS
1  'BAD'   200   0 
2   NULL   200   0
3   NULL   300   1
4   'OK'    0    2
```

if I do

```
Select * from table where STATUS != 'OK'
```

I expect

```
ID STATUS VALUE POS 
1  'BAD'   200   0
2   NULL   200   0
3   NULL   300   1
```

But I get

```
ID STATUS VALUE POS 
1  'BAD'   200   0
```

I want to know why, I know I can do something else like Where ID = 4, but why the query above returns an empty result for NULL values?

Thanks

Comment: NULL is neither equal to nor not equal to anything, even itself. If you want NULL you have to ask for it: `WHERE STATUS != 'OK' OR STATUS IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing with NULL is always NULL. Think about NULL like it is "unknown value". Does some unknown value is not equal to 'OK'? this is unknown... so the result is NULL.

In logical expressions NULL is treated as FALSE. So you do not receive the rows which you want to receive.

You must either apply additional check for NULL value (`WHERE status != 'OK' OR status IS NULL`) or convert NULL value to some definite constant value before compare (`WHERE COALESCE(status, '') != 'OK'`).

Pay attention - this interpretation differs from one used in CHECK constraint (including FOREIGN KEY constraint) in which NULL value is treated as "matched".

Comment: using functions such as `coalesce(status,'')` can have detrimental effects on query performance, so it is advisable to get into a habit of using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @PaulMaxwell I'm just listing the options, not giving them an estimate. I know that function usage will make the expression non-sargable. But there are cases when function usage may be useful enough - for example, when investigated rowset is already nonsargable (the simplest case - the rowset is produced by complex/recursive CTE).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to use "equal" or "not equal" for NULL values

You **MUST** use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` e.g:

```
Select * from table where STATUS != 'OK' OR Status IS NULL
```

Comment: What if there are more than one that are not NUL???

Comment: I changed the example for a better demosntration, thanks!

Comment: Ok I understand, thaks